# Jetpack Compose: How to listen column currently visible items like lazycolumn?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to use Column instead of LazyColumn, and make it scrollable by  `Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState)` , is there any way to get currently visible items key that users see on the screen?

Comment: The solution might depend on exactly what you are going for. I had a need to know if one particular item in a scrollable column was currently visible in order to change the visibility of a helper button which scrolls that item into view - I imagine that code could be adapted to observe multiple items, but without knowing your real use case I'm not sure it's a valid answer to your question.

Comment: @nEx.Software I want to get the text of first visible element in scrollable column and when users scroll I want to update the a state that represent that text, I previously used LazyColumn but there was a bit of performance issue in older devices, so I decides to migrate to normal Column.
I used ``` LaunchedEffect(key1 = chapter.id) {
                            lastChapterId = chapter
                        }```
for temporary soloution

Comment: I write this LaunchEffect on every Text Composable that need to get the state of it, which I think its not a good solution because I think this code causes recomposable every second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive that I fully understand, so this may be off base but here's some code that keeps track of the position of the items within a scrollable column and updates a text whenever the first visible item changes. Performance seems okay, at least for a list of items that would be reasonable for a non-lazy column.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Example() {
    val positions = remember { items.map { 0f }.toMutableStateList() }

    val ss = rememberScrollState()
    val firstVisibleItem by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            positions.indexOfLast {
                it <= ss.value
            }
        }
    }
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(
            items.getOrElse(firstVisibleItem) { "None "},
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.LightGray)
                .padding(16.dp)
        )
        Column(
            Modifier
                .verticalScroll(ss)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                Text(
                    text = item,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(100.dp)
                        .onGloballyPositioned {
                            positions[index] = it.positionInParent().y
                        }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As an aside, I'd be surprised if a normal scrollable column had better performance than a lazy one unless the item count is very small.

Comment: I wasn't successful in doing what I wanted, because I think when using verticalScrolling all composable with be built on UI and when user scroll through them, all component exists and by using globalpostion which update it postion on y axis, it would decrease the performace I think, I better go with Lazy Column at least I can get currently visible item key, thanks for answering